# Make a Countdown timer using AWT

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I've tried to make a countdown timer in AWT Frame, but was trapped with change of digit in label. I tried to use thread to solve the problem. Here is my unfinished code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Frame app = new Frame("Time Ticker");
    //label is used to display digit here I will let the app count from 0-99;
    final Label label = new Label(); 
    //set it final bc this can be accessed in Anonymous Inner class

    Thread threadDigit = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
           for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
              label.setText(""+i);  
           //Problem: Reported As Error Why I cannot setText this way?
              try{
                //so the count down process will be more obvious
                sleep(500);
              }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("insomia");
              }       
        }

    };
    threadDigit.start();
    app.add(label);
    app.setSize(300,400);
    app.setVisible(true);


}
```

Even though I did this way, the outcome is no thread sleep at all, only showing 99, I know I start threadDigit only once and so the for loop did everything from 0-99 and displayed 99, wondering how can I see digit tick from 0-99 with 500 millisecond's interval. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems to be fine, just try adding the label to frame and setting it visible before calling start

Comment: Do you use an IDE like Eclipse?  Because final keyword starts with lowercase f.

Comment: @k.c. Yes but here I hand typed the code haha

Comment: No problem  :)  good it works now.

Comment: You should better not access UI components from another thread than the AWT event dispatch thread. So instead of directly calling `label.setText`, wrap it into a `Runnable` and push it on the AWT event queue by calling `EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable)`!